# Ubuntu Unity multitouch features

Tags: unity, touchpad, gestures

I noticed that Linux supports some gestures on my touchpad, eg. 3 fingers tap/swipe up, down, left, right and same with 4 fingers.

Unity reacts with some of these gestures and this works pretty smooth.
For example four finger swipe right/left shows/hides autohidden panel.
It would be a lot more usefull if I could switch workspaces this way.
Is there any chance to customize these actions?

I know about solutions like touch-egg, but it seem too problematic. Also there is such feature already built-in this DE. I prefer to avoid third-party stuff if I can.

Comment: You might look at `Easystroke`. It allows you to create custom gestures. I've got mine setup to switch workspaces with a mouse gesture.

Comment: You might be interested in Gnome-Shell/desktop as it focus more on touch gestures. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8d8mAAgkgo

Comment: I know about easystroke - that's not what I'm looking for. I'm not going to draw letters - more than that I'd like to NOT install third party software for this as the features is inside shell I'm using already.
Also I know Gnome-shell as I used it for very long. Unfortunately It has some lag issue - it's not smooth at all - especially after some time of using, but that's another topic.